# Zend Framework :: Is this code good for user login (Its begining- because that I want to know if its can be improve)

Tags: model-view-controller, zend-framework, zend-controller

I new in Zend.

Main Question:
**Is this code good for user login (Its beginning- because that I want to know if its can be improve)?**

**Thanks**

**view** index.phtml

```
<? echo $this->form
```

**controller** IndexAction.php

```
public function indexAction() {
        $form=new Application_Form_Login();
        $this->view->form = $form;
        if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
            $formData = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
            if ($form->isValid($formData)) {
                echo " test value username: ".$form->getValue('username');
            }
        }
    }
```

**form** Login.php

```
public function init() {


        $this->setMethod('post');
        $this->setName('user login');
        $username = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('username');
        $username->setLabel("username")
                ->setRequired(true)
                ->addFilter('StripTags')
                ->addFilter('StringTrim')
                ->addValidator('NotEmpty');

        $password = new Zend_Form_Element_Password('password');
        $password->setLabel('password')
                ->setRequired(true)
                ->addFilter('StripTags')
                ->addFilter('StringTrim')
                ->addValidator('NotEmpty');

        $submit = new Zend_Form_Element_Submit('submit');


        $this->addElements(array($username, $password, $submit));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far, so good. IMO there's nothing to improve on this further. It renders the form and if the request is POST it validates the form against the data in the POST array.

Answer (score 1):

what is really special in your code? standart pattern.